# Removing the outlines of polygon islands within holes when using smoothr's fill_holes

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

I am joining multiple adjoining polygons  together and removing any holes from the now single polygon using `fill_holes` in `smoothr`. However, if a hole has another polygon (or island) within it, the outline of that polygon remains. Is there a way these outlines can be removed/dissolved?

```
library(sf)
library(smoothr)

download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-KcZce0jgIV0fwG797mq7FB5WjxwtKqX" , destfile="Zones.zip")
unzip("Zones.zip")

Zones <- st_read("Zones.gpkg")

Threshold <- units::set_units(1000, km^2)

Zones_No_Holes <- fill_holes(Zones %>% st_union, threshold = Threshold)

plot(Zones_No_Holes, col="aliceblue")
```

[image: current output]

Comment: perhaps `sf::st_union`? Oh, I see you have it there...Hummm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `zones_no_holes` to 'POLYGON' and then `st_union` the result should get you there.

```
zones_no_holes <- fill_holes(Zones %>% st_union, threshold = threshold) %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  st_union()

plot(zones_no_holes, col = 'aliceblue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to do this with multiple features that are a mixture of polygons and multipart polygons. Then a modification of @mrhellmann's method does the job:

```
zones_no_holes <- fill_holes(Zones %>% st_union, threshold = threshold) %>%
  st_cast('MULTIPOLYGON') %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  st_cast('MULTIPOLYGON') %>%
  group_by(objectid) %>%
  summarize(geom = st_union(geom))
```

(replace objectid with whatever unqiue group ID you have)